# Can't remove entity with a foreign key relationship in entity framework asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two entities (SpaceEvent, RegisteredStudent). I want to remove a registered student from the space event, but I'm getting this exception

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Here is my code

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
Student student = _studentRepository.Find(id);

var spaceEvent = _spaceEventRepository.Find(eventId);
var registeredStudents = spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents;

RegisteredStudent studentToUnregister = registeredStudents.First(w => w.StudentId == student.StudentId);
spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents.Remove(studentToUnregister);
_spaceEventRepository.Save();
```

Here are my two entities

```
public class YogaSpaceEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int SpaceEventId { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTimeScheduled { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AppointmentLength { get; set; }
    public int StatusEnum { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student.RegisteredStudent> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int SpaceRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SpaceRefId")]
    public virtual Space Space { get; set; }
}

public class RegisteredStudent
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentRegisteredId { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string AspNetUserRefId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [Required]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }


    [Index]
    public int SpaceEventRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SpaceEventRefId")]
    public virtual SpaceEvent SpaceEvent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your mapping creates a `RegisteredStudent` table with a non-nullable `SpaceEventRefId` column, so once a Student is removed from some space event , it must be assigned to join in another space event or the `SpaceEventRefId` should be set to `null`. If your design allows a student not to have to join a space event, then `SpaceEventRefId` should be nullable, try replacing `public int SpaceEventRefId` with `public int? SpaceEventRefId`

Comment: I don't want it to join to another space event. I want to delete that entry from the table all together. What would I need to do in this case? Should I just remove the foreigh key to space event ?

Comment: You may not understand what it will be deleted here, Do you really want to delete the related student from the table `Student`? just because he does not join in a space event?

Comment: yes I want to delete the row entry from 'registeredStudent' all together. I don't want any row left over with a null in 'spaceeventrefid' and I want to delete it from my spaceevent repository, so I would need to access the registeredstudent through the spaceevent, like I show in my code above.

Comment: maybe I can somehow put a predicate on the remove() call to registeredstudents. Something like remove().where(...) ?? is this possible?

Comment: For what you want, you should delete the student directly like this `if(spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents.Any(e=>e.StudentId == student.StudentId)) registeredStudents.Remove(student);`

Comment: this isn't any different then what I already have, you have just wrapped a logical condition around it. So I still receive the same exception

Comment: the condition is to check if that student joins in any space event before removing it from `registeredStudents`. However I don't think we need that condition. Be sure your code is removed. What you need here is get `student` and call `registeredStudents.Remove(student)`. That's all (of course `SaveChanges()` should be called finally).

Comment: BTW, if you do not use DbContext directly, then you must have some repository for `RegisteredStudents`, such as named `_registeredStudentRepository`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing above in the code I posted and I'm receiving an exception from the save(). Please look again at my code above or please provide some code snippet for me to try. thanks!

Comment: please update the code you tried first. As I said, the code you posted originally should be almost ***removed***, just keep the code finding `student`.

Comment: everything is updated as shown above. I have no registeredStudent repository, I have only a SpaceEvent repository. So I need to update the regsiteredstudent THROUGH the SpaceEvent repo.

Comment: so you designed it wrongly. You cannot delete student via SpaceEvent, it's a one-many relationship. The many-side entities cannot be removed that way, they always require some space event (it's not nullable) ***or*** they should be deleted directly.

Comment: ok, so how should the entities be designed so that I can delete RegisteredStudents from/through a SpaceEvent? Just one question - if I do delete them directly, given my current design would there still be a foreign key exception error? Just because I delte them directly through some RegisteredStudentRepository doesn't mean the relationships change does it?

Comment: I understand that you have a table such as `RegisteredStudent` right? So your current design does not allow you to delete from that table directly. Without using repository, you can always do something like this `context.RegisteredStudent.Remove(student)`, but when using repository, you need some repository for `RegisteredStudent`. Again I confirm that you can only delete registered student from `RegisteredStudents` ***directly***, no other way.

Comment: When you do something like this `spaceEvent.RegisteredStudents.Remove(studentToUnregister)` - it just tries to set the foreign key column `SpaceEventRefId` to null. But it's not nullable, so it throws the exception. So technically it cannot delete the row unless you delete the row explicitly.

Comment: ah ok I got it! So I added a call to my repo '_SpaceEventRepo.UnregisterStudent(student)' and it works. It just seems stupid that I can add a student but can't delete one without using the context?

Comment: deleting an entity always requires you to delete it from the entity set, if deleting it via nav properties, actually ***the relationship*** will be changed. So then it depends on the kind of relationship, for `one-many` the many-side end (registered student) will have the reference nav property (SpaceEvent) set to `null`. That is translated to sql query and the foreign key column `SpaceEventRefId` will be set to `null`). ***What you changed is the relationship, not the entities***.